# EF Core Many-to-Many Relationship not Working Properly with Network Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm creating a many-to-many relationship between `Members` and `Books` they have read. My goal is to be able to display all the books a given `Member` has read, as well as all the members who have read a given `Book`.

Each `Member` has a `List<BookMember> BooksRead`, and each `Book` has a `List<BookMember> MembersWhoHaveRead`. This works fine and there is a properly created join table in the database for these relationships.

My UI succeeds in adding a `BookMember` to the join table when a user adds a book they have read, but the `List<BookMember>` in `Member` fails to recognize this addition, so the following code continues to display the message: "You haven't read any books yet. Add one below!", and the book that was just added is still available in the drop-down menu:

```html
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <b>Books</b>
                </div>
                @if (Model.UserProfileUpdateModel.BooksRead.Count > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (var book in Model.Books)
                    {
                        if (Model.UserProfileUpdateModel.HasReadBook(book))
                        {
                            <div class="card-body">
                                @book.ToString()
                            </div>

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="card-body">You haven't read any books yet. Add one below!</div>
                }
                <div class="card-body">
                    <label for="addBooks">Select a book below to add it to your list.</label>
                    <select asp-for="UserProfileUpdateModel.AddedBook" id="addBooks">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                        @foreach (var book in Model.Books)
                        {
                            if (!(Model.UserProfileUpdateModel.HasReadBook(book)))
                            {
                                <option value="@book.Id">@book.ToString()</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This code should display all books the `Member` (referenced from `UserProfileUpdateModel`) has read, and the message "You haven't read any books yet. Add one below!" if there are no books. It should also display a drop-down menu listing all available books which this `Member` has not read.

I have checked that the `HasReadBook` method works as intended; it just looks at the `Member`'s `BooksRead` list and returns true if the book is in that list.

Interestingly, when the `BookMember` is first added to the database, the drop-down menu updates as intended in order to not show the just-added book. But if the page is reloaded or the application rerun, the drop-down menu does show that book.

Essentially, I need to know why my many-to-many relationship isn't updating the lists within `Book` and `Member`, even when it is updating the database. Here is the relevant code from `Member`, `Book`, and `BookMember`:

```cs
public class Member : BaseEntity
    {
     ...
        public List<BookMember> BooksRead { get; } = new List<BookMember>();
     ...
    }

public class Book : BaseEntity
    {
        ...
        public List<BookMember> MembersWhoHaveRead { get; } = new List<BookMember>();
       ...
    }

public class BookMember
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; } = new Book();

        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        public Member Member { get; set; } = new Member(string.Empty);
    }
```

For completion's sake, here is the `HasReadBook` method as well:

```cs
public bool HasReadBook(Book book)
        {
            if (BooksRead == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (BookMember bookMember in BooksRead)
            {
                if (bookMember != null && bookMember.Book != null && bookMember.Book.Equals(book))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Edit: here is the `BookMemberConfig`:

```cs
public class BookMemberConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BookMember>
    {

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BookMember> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => new { x.BookId, x.MemberId });

            builder.HasOne(bookmember => bookmember.Book)
                .WithMany(b => b.MembersWhoHaveRead)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.BookId);

            builder.HasOne(bookmember => bookmember.Member)
                .WithMany(m => m.BooksRead)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MemberId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how have you configured those relationships in your DbContext class?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are created and populated correctly, it's likely that you're either not retrieving the related entities in your queries and/or not configuring properly the navigation properties.

**Retrieving the related entities**

Make sure you're using `Include` and `ThenInclude` in the relevant read methods, i.e.:

```cs
ICollection<Member> LoadAllMembers()
{
    return _dbContext.Members
        .Include(member => member.BooksRead)
        .ThenInclude(bookMember => bookMember.Book)
        .ToList();
}
```

**Configuring the navigation properties**

If you're using an EF Core version older than v5.0.0, I recommend following this series of articles by Arthur Vickers (EF Engineering Manager) about setting up many-to-many relationships and properly configuring associated navigation properties, because it's not something trivial to do.

[Part 1](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/), [part 2](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-2-hiding-as-ienumerable/), [part 3](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-3-hiding-as-icollection/) and [part 4](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/).

These kind of joint entities [aren't required anymore from EF Core v5.0.0](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10508), where basic many-to-many relationships configuration gets simplified.

Comment: I tried this: `var member = await _appDbContext.Members
        .Include(member => member.BooksRead)
        .ThenInclude(bookMember => bookMember.Book)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == applicationUser.Id);` but am still running into the same problem

Comment: I would suggest configuring the navigation properties as described in the articles I mentioned in the answer ([this is the final part](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/)), because it's tricky to make everything work as expected. They are written by one of the main EF Core maintainers.